# Can OPCUA clients send HELLO Message in Chunks?

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I am using a [Prosys Opcua client](https://downloads.prosysopc.com/opc-ua-client-downloads.php) as a test client for my server. According to the OPCUA specification, the client has to send a HEL packet to the server, then the server will acknowledge the client and the flow will continue up to a point where a connection is established.

I've noticed that the prosys client sends the HELLO message in chunks, its sends HE then L and continues to send bytes until the the HELLO packet is complete.

I find this behavior to be abnormal , and i can't seem anywhere in the specification where the spec says HELLO message can be transmitted in chunks.

When i use other clients , the HELLO message is sent as a single packet.

Below is a snapshot for wireshark showing packets sent by prosys client, i have highlighted the hello packet, the final hello only contains the endpoint url, all other attributes of the HELLO message are sent above the HELLO packet. 
[image]

Is this standard behavior ? if yes which part of the specification mentions about this ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can know, this is compliant, although sub-optimal. The OPC UA TCP mapping does not concern itself with how the messages are split into network packets. Why should it? That is a low-level detail. Other protocols that build upon TCP do not care either (e.g. HTTP).

No part of the UA spec needs to mention this as "allowed", because there is no reason why it shouldn't be allowed - it is simply a property of some underlying protocol, and OPC UA cannot mandate that underlying protocols should behave differently from their standards.

Note that you have written "...transmitted in chunks". Just to be clear, the "chunks" that you are observing are IP packets that carry TCP segments. They are not "message chunks" that OPC UA Part 6 (Mappings) describes - they cannot be, as they apply to UA secure conversation protocol, and the Hello message is sent before that protocol comes to use.

Comment: this makes sense; since the specification mentions the first request from the client should be a HELLO message, it is valid to expect a HELLO message from the client even if the packets are sent at once or in chunks.